Self-hosted simultaneous multi-user webapp for editing ultra-simple (non-formula) table
I need the following app:

table editor for very simple tables, i.e. max. 100 rows and 10 columns
no formulas needed, it will just be used to collect data
simultaneous multi-user, i.e. everyone sees all the cursors of other users and updates are real-time

Limitations:

self-hosted, i.e. runs on one of our internal servers. And offline, read as: does not require an external Internet connection for anything
linux-based, any standard apt package requirements are ok
may be a Docker container
gratis, open-source preferred

